# Do I need to use core data for RSS feed app?

Tags: ios, swift, rss, feed

I'm trying to build an app (using Swift), it will have different functions (perhaps login, news, small forum, statistic...), but in general, I will have rss feed generated from the web.

My question is - what's the best practice for to store the RSS? Do I need to use core data?

For login, its obvious, I need web server (Parse or whatever), but for feed data?

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* CoreData, but it's always recommanded by Apple to use it when saving and handling data (from RSS feeds or else). Also, you should look at [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) (which I created!) rather than poll the feeds yourself.